# Woocommerce My Account Screen Navigation Links area are messed up

Tags: woocommerce, navigation, account

After some update (probably theme...) my account navigation links are messed up and going onto 2 lines and are indented. (see attached pic). I have tried to adjust it via css customization but I am not having any luck. 
I believe I am trying to adjust .woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation - not sure

Hoping someone can help 
[image: My account screenshot],

Answer (score 0):

right click on the main div and check if they are getting enough space to spread them self. if it is space issue then increase there width by adding css in theme customization menu at admin side.